# Two column layout with new line break

Tags: html, css, layout

i am experimenting with a multi-column magazine style layout for an editorial project.

Due to the increasing size of the monitors, i wanted to  use of all available inches of the monitor by creating layouts very similar to paper magazine (two or three columns per page).

I am using TipTap editor for article management (as it returns very clean HTML code) and in frontend i get this html output:

[image]

I am using the css columns class to split the article in two:

```
   article {
       columns: 2;
    }
```

But the result is this:
[image]

I would like to divide all the **h2** as settling paragraphs, so that i could have the chapter exploded horizontally, for example like this:
[image]

Using Pseudo-classes is it possible to intercept H2?

Comment: Are you able to change the HTML or not?

Comment: @AHaworth Technically yes, but html editing I left it as a last option

Comment: I meant, are you allowed to change it in any way - if you can then I'd do it with JavaScript so it's a general solution and you won't have to go in by hand altering things each time you add a chapter etc. Is it OK to use a bit of JS?

Comment: Ah forgive me you mean via DOM, the answer is absolutely yes

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to put each chapter in a div and they will stack on top of each other like your desired result.

HTML

```
<article>
  <div class="block">
    <h2>Chapter 1</h2>
    <h3> 1.1 - The First</h3>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <h3> 1.2 - The Second</h3>
    <p>...</p>
    <h3> 1.3 - The Third</h3>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h2>Chapter 2</h2>
    <h3> 2.1 - The First</h3>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

CSS

```
.block {
  column-count:2;
  column-gap: 30px;
  margin: 20px 0 50px 0;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/halfandhalfhd/pen/PoamByX

Answer (score 0):

You may give a try to hudge margin for the next(s) H2 found.

Here is an example of the idea with 3 articles with different contents length behind h2s to test different cases:

```css
article {
  column-count: 2;
  overflow: hidden;/* chrome fix */
}
h2 ~ h2 {
  margin-top: 100em;/* trick */
}
article :last-child {
  margin-bottom: -200em;/* chrome fix */
}

/* styling*/h1,h2,h3 {
  margin:0 0 1em;
  text-decoration:underline;
  text-align:center;
}

article {

  border:solid;
  margin:2em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Column CSS test</h1>
<article>
  <h2>first</h2>
  <h3>1.1</h3>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  <h3>1.2</h3>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  
  
  <h3>1.3</h3>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  <h2>second</h2>
  <h3>2.1</h3>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  <h3>2.2</h3>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  
  <h3>2.3</h3>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. END</p>
</article>

<article>
  <h2>first</h2>
  <h3>1.1</h3>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  <h2>second</h2>
  <h3>2.1</h3>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  <h3>2.2</h3>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  
  <h3>2.3</h3>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>

  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. END</p>
</article>

<article>
  <h2>first</h2>
  <h3>1.1</h3>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  <h3>1.2</h3>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  
  
  <h3>1.3</h3>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  <h2>second</h2>
  <h3>2.1</h3>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. END</p>

</article>
```

made with FF and fixed for chrome, but needs further testing through more browsers & OS ( edge, safari, win,linux,android,linux, ..)